# Javascript Else If Style Changing Issue

Tags: javascript, if-statement

JS:

```
var div = document.getElementById('testdiv');
var button = document.getElementById('testbutton');

function showNotification(){
    if(div.style.display = "none") {
        div.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        div.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

The code above simply shows and hides a div, Well thats what its meant to do but for some reason it wont hide using display: none when its set to display block. I also tried an else if statement but nothing will work.

P.S:
I know I can just do 2 functions, hide/showNotification and just make it change the onclick from hide to show respectively but its not a great way to do it.

Comment: Look at the if condition, and know that == or === are comparison operators, and = is an assignment operator. Also, since you've tagged this question `jQuery`, you could just use `$('#testdiv').toggle();`.

Comment: Oops jquery shouldnt be there.

Comment: The original code with the single = was setting the display to "none" and then immediately setting it back to "block". In the future for debugging try inserting some alert("hi") statements to see if the code if even getting executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss = in your condition:

The right code is:

```
function showNotification(){
if(div.style.display == "none") {
    div.style.display = "block";
} else {
    div.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nati and Mike, Can't believe I missed out on that xD